# How to use react-google-charts into Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, react-google-charts

I used react-google-charts for Reactjs, then I wanted to use it for Vuejs, but because I didn't know how to transfer react-google-charts to Vuejs. Has anyone used it, show me how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts` ?

Comment: @NishantPatel, can react-google-charts be used in vuejs?

Comment: Nope react-google-charts is specific to reactjs implementation, you must use a vuejs wrapper for google-charts.